# convert JSON to ListView.builder in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, android-listview

I'm new in programming so please be patient with me, I'm trying to convert this JSON to be displayed like this design,
I have done JSON decode but for sample JSON so I understand how it works but for complex one I'm confused so I really appreciate if any one help

JSON Code:

```
[
  {
    "Category": "Gro",
    "stores": [
      {
        "name": "market",
        "logo_url": "https://www.google.com/signpost-150x150.png",
        "phone_1": "1111111111",
        "phone_2": "1111111111",
        "location": "https://maps.google.com/location"
      },
      {
        "name": "mall",
        "logo_url": "https://www.google.com/signpost-150x150.png",
        "phone_1": "1111111111",
        "phone_2": "1111111111",
        "location": "https://maps.google.com/location"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category": "Food",
    "stores": [
      {
        "name": "Food Time",
        "logo_url": "https://www.google.com/signpost-150x150.png",
        "phone_1": "1111111111",
        "phone_2": "1111111111",
        "location": "https://maps.google.com/location"
      },
      {
        "name": "let's eat",
        "logo_url": "https://www.google.com/signpost-150x150.png",
        "phone_1": "1111111111",
        "phone_2": "1111111111",
        "location": "https://maps.google.com/location"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category": "Personal Care",
    "stores": [
      {
        "name": "Body",
        "logo_url": "https://www.google.com/signpost-150x150.png",
        "phone_1": "1111111111",
        "phone_2": "1111111111",
        "location": "https://maps.google.com/location"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hair",
        "logo_url": "https://www.google.com/signpost-150x150.png",
        "phone_1": "1111111111",
        "phone_2": "1111111111",
        "location": "https://maps.google.com/location"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**#################################################**

[What I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sSfF.png)

**#################################################**

**This is what I have come up with**

```
import 'package:side_menu.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Future<List> shopsList() async {
  Response response = await get('JSON URL');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var shopsData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return shopsData;
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
}

class ShowShops extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: SideMenu(),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: shopsList(),
                  builder: (context, shops) {
                    if (shops.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: shops.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          Map shopInfo = shops.data[index];
                          String cat = shopInfo[index]['Category'];
                          return Card(
                            child: Text(cat),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child: SpinKitWave(
                        color: Color(0xff023246),
                        size: 100,
                      ),
                      //CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***But I get error and I'm confused how to display shops under category***

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: http.get('https://dc-apps.net/map/services.json'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          List data = json.decode(snapshot.data.body);
          // print(data);
          List categoriesnames = [];
          List stores = [];
          data.forEach((element) {
            categoriesnames.add(element["Category"]);
            stores.add(element['stores']);
          });

          // return Text('see');
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              //      print(stores[index][index]['name']);
              return CardItem(
                categoryname: categoriesnames[index],
                sotories: stores[index],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String categoryname;
  List sotories;
  CardItem({this.categoryname, this.sotories});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(categoryname),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: sotories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(sotories[index]['name']),
                subtitle: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(sotories[index]['phone_1']),
                    Text(sotories[index]['phone_2']),
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(sotories[index]['logo_url']),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `,` line 9

`"phone_2": "1111111111"`

Comment: Convert your JSON to List of object and use your List<Category>
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/.